# Need help with this derivation (Sound intensity)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics

I will copy a little bit of what my textbook says. By the way, we're talking about sound here.

$$Intensity = (0.5)BwkA^2$$

The textbook claims that by using the relationships $w=vk$ and $v^2=\frac{B}{\rho}$, we can transform the previous equation into

$$I = (0.5)(\rho)(B)^{0.5} w^2 A^2$$

So I'm here manipulating these equations and can't see how they got to that derivation. Any ideas?

Comment: $w = uk = k\sqrt{B/\rho} \implies I = 0.5A^2k^2B^{3/2}/\rho^{1/2}$, the relation for $\rho$ to $w$ and $k$ and $u$, does the rest

Answer (score 1):

From what you have; $$k=\frac{\omega}{\nu}=\frac{\omega}{\sqrt{\frac B{\rho}}}=\frac{\omega\sqrt{\rho}}{\sqrt{B}}$$
So, $$I=\frac12 B\omega kA^2=\frac12B\omega\frac{\omega\sqrt{\rho}}{\sqrt{B}}A^2=\frac12\sqrt {B\rho}\omega^2A^2$$
**Dimensional analysis can asist you in checking the truth of the above formula.**